# Number not displayed in parentheses

Tags: xetex, xepersian

When I put a number between parentheses it will vanished:

What is wrong?

MWE:

```
‎\documentclass{article}‎‎
‎\usepackage{hyperref}‎‎
‎‎‎
\usepackage{syntonly}

‎\usepackage{xepersian}‎‎

‎\settextfont{Tahoma‎}‎‎
‎\setdigitfont{Tahoma‎}‎
‎\setlatintextfont{Tahoma‎‎}‎
‎\begin{document}‎

‎\tableofcontents‎
‎\section{Test‎}
    ‎sdfsd‎ ‎f‎ ‎sfsdf‎ ‎5 ‎sdfs‎ ‎df‎ ‎(55)‎‎ ‎dgsdf‎

‎\end{document}‎‎
```

`55` will not be displayed.

Update: When I use `\usepackage{xltxtra‎}‎‎` instead of `‎\usepackage{xepersian}‎‎‎` it is displayed.

Is there a bug in the [xepersian](http://ctan.org/pkg/xepersian) package?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. For example, does this problem only happen in XeTeX, only with this particular font or language, etc.?

Comment: @Mike Updated,  ....

Comment: When I copy the above code to a file there seems to be some Unicode (zero-width?)space displayed as `<200e>` in Vim. My XeLaTeX didn't like that at all. Maybe this is the source of your issues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are certainly using MikTeX. XeTex binary in MikTeX is buggy. Use TeXLive 2011 instead. See [here](http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/xetex/2011-July/020884.html), [here](http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/xetex/2011-July/020885.html) and [here](http://www.parsilatex.com/joomla/index.php?option=com_smf&Itemid=0&topic=1732.0). The last link is in Persian. I reported this bug of MiKTeX about a year ago to the author of MiKTeX but this bug has not been fixed yet.

Certainly not a `xepersian` bug because the following minimal working example gives the same result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\font\test="Scheherazade/ICU:script=arab;language=DFLT;"
\begin{document}\test
123 (123 abc 

123 (123abc

345  789)
\end{document}
```

So this certainly is a bug of MiKTeX.

Comment: No, Please read answers carefully before commenting.

Comment: I am using miktek 2.9. The code that is mentioned in first link work correctly in my system.

Comment: If that works on your system, then your example should also work on your system.

Comment: Thanks. is it possible to  patch/update XeTex binary in MikTeX to fix its bug? Or any other trick instead of migrating to Texlive?

Comment: Well, the only way to patch XeTeX binary is that you need to compile XeTeX from source yourself. To update/replace XeTeX binary, you may use `W32TeX`: http://www.w32tex.org/

Comment: I switched to LiveTex and all thing is now better!