# Parenthesis problem in Xelatex

Tags: xetex

The number parenthesis `()` scuh as `(1)` `(2)` etc disappear when compiled on xelatex/polyglossia. Adding space character inside the parenthesis is not a solution in my case. So need your help desperately.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[quiet]{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{hmargin={0.04in,0.04in}, vmargin={0.04in,0.03in}, paperwidth=81mm, paperheight=105mm}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=0.8]{Tahoma}

\begin{document}
\centering

\textarabic{نتبينت (9) نتيسن} 
% Parenthesis with number in it is ignored.

\begin{Arabic}
نتبينت (9) نتيسن
\end{Arabic}
% Parenthesis with number in it is ignored.

%However following works:

\begin{Arabic}
نتبينت ( 9 ) نتيسن
\end{Arabic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have no problem with current TeXLive

Answer (score 2):

This is a MiKTeX bug which should be fixed by next update. Please see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52575/number-not-displayed-in-parentheses), and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58335/tables-are-not-numbered-using-polyglossia-in-hebrew) for the same bug with the XeTeX binary included in MiKTeX 2.9. As you can see [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3532167&group_id=10783&atid=110783), the next update of MiKTeX 2.9, should fix the bug.

Comment: As a work-around (until the new version has rolled out) one can separate the problematic glyphs e.g. with `(\mbox{9})`.